# Tool for Requirements checking and commenting?

Tags: email, document-management, google-drive, dropbox, sharepoint

I regularly give and get a list of requirements by email.

Typically these requirements require some comments, documents to specific items and responses from different parties. I am thinking about an example for a conveyance. Typically involves a buyer, a seller, their banks, their lawyers and the banks lawyers.

An example list might be
I need an update of Doc X
You said "xyz" did you mean "abc"
You need to know this

Then there are 8 parties to this conversation
A. Buyer
B. Buyers Lawyer
C. Buyers Bank
D. Buyers Bank Lawyer
E. Seller
F. Sellers Lawyer
G. Sellers Bank
H. Sellers Bank Lawyer

Typically parts of this conversation only go on between 2 of the parties. But typically a comment from say Party D, the Buyers bank Lawyer goes through Party B to the Party F to Party E. The Seller, Party E, responds.

Yes I meant "abc"
Then the buyer (via all the people) writes
I have uploaded Doc X

The question is Is it done this way as lawyers are non technical, and can't come up with a digital way to figure this out?
Or is it more about the distance between parties?
Or could this be improved with some type of system? If so, what off the shelf software would work?

Project based, several users.
Cheap, simple, easy authentication for involved people to simplify things as much as possible.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

We use Confluence for this purpose. Some investment is required in building a template to capture the requirements from different stakeholder groups' points of view but this can be evolved over time.

Anyone can access (with appropriate read/edit rights) at any time so good for fostering collaboration.

We encourage stakeholders to update the information and then use it as the centrepiece of group discussions on a video meeting to gain consensus and make project and engineering decisions.

Comment: Thanks @mhaselup I will check it out. Atlassian are pretty good, love their tools like Trello, is more about making this as simple as possible for non tech people, so will be interesting. Given how many different parties, with different IT and security policies to make this work.

Comment: I have heard back from Atlassian, not a bad tool. I think it is a giant leap for the parties in this to join it is all...

Comment: So my parties are captive-they are inside and known to the organisation. I can setup particular "projects" and invite a subset of people to participate. In your case I believe you are dealing with individuals for a specific transaction and may not want everyone to be able to review/edit the information. It might take some thought to work out how you wish all these stakeholders to interact and then design a solution but you have to do that whatever tool you use.